# I developed a controller in magento. how to access it from frontend?

Tags: php, magento-1.7

I am developing a module, and I developed a controller in magento. how to access it from frontend? please provide me config settings

Comment: replace this "productextension" with your module name, and then... http://urdomain/your_module_name/urcontrollername/action/

Comment: its working now:)  Thanx alot buddy. i got my controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code in your config: `<frontend>
        <routers>
            <productextension>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>GreenOrigin_ProductExtension</module>
                    <frontName>productextension</frontName>
                </args>
            </productextension>
        </routers>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <productextension>
                    <file>productextension.xml</file>
                </productextension>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>`